# Indexing and querying JSON array

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have JSON values like this stored in a table:

```
{  
   "properties":[  
      {  
         "address":{  
            "value":"A3",
            "name":"",
            "prop":"",
            "path":[  
               "RealOptionsList9293"
            ],
            "type":"local"
         },
         "value":{  
            "type":11,
            "value":"portland"
         },
         "dependents":[  

         ],
         "save":true
      }
   ]
}
```

I'd like to index on address.value and value.value so that I can query on them. MSDN examples are for basic property using computed column. It does not cover indexing an array. Is indexing possible on array? Any example will be helpful.

I'd like to query for rows with:

```
JSON_VALUE(mycolumn, '$.properties[*].address.value') = 'A3'
AND JSON_VALUE(mycolumn, $.properties[*].value.value) = 'portland'
```

I don't see `[*]` syntax. Should I use `OPENJSON()` instead? If I use it, should I use a materialized view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query a `JSON` array, `OPENJSON()` is more appropriate:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   JsonData nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTo #Data (JsonData)
VALUES (N'{  
   "properties":[  
      {  
         "address":{  
            "value":"A3",
            "name":"",
            "prop":"",
            "path":[  
               "RealOptionsList9293"
            ],
            "type":"local"
         },
         "value":{  
            "type":11,
            "value":"portland"
         },
         "dependents":[  

         ],
         "save":true
      },
      {  
         "address":{  
            "value":"A4",
            "name":"",
            "prop":"",
            "path":[  
               "RealOptionsList9293"
            ],
            "type":"local"
         },
         "value":{  
            "type":11,
            "value":"portland"
         },
         "dependents":[  

         ],
         "save":true
      }
   ]
}')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.JsonData, '$.properties') WITH (
   AddressValue nvarchar(1000) '$.address.value',
   ValueValue nvarchar(1000) '$.value.value'
) j
WHERE j.AddressValue = 'A3' AND ValueValue = 'portland'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to query JSON arrays or objects you should use `JSON_QUERY` which is designed to work with that. `JSON_VALUE` is designed to return a scalar, thus, if you use `JSON_VALUE` with address, value or even dependents (in your JSON), it'll always returns null. But if you use it with save, it'll return its value.

So, what you need to do is something like this :

```
SELECT 
    JSON_VALUE([Address],'$.value') 
FROM (
SELECT 
    JSON_QUERY(@json,'$.properties[0].address')  AS [Address]
,   JSON_QUERY(@json,'$.properties[0].value')  AS [Value]
,   JSON_QUERY(@json,'$.properties[0].dependents')  AS [dependents]

) arrays
```

Comment: In my case, number of elements in properties array is a variable. Above approach will not work as you may have one or more elements.

Comment: @frosty the above approach works fine with the example you've provided. If the json is more complex than this, then JSON_QUERY should do the trick.